# What would be the best way to texture a line around my object?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I've imported an object of a sock into blender and I need to add an extra line on the design of the sock. I would like to know, what would be the easiest way to do this? Is this something done in Blender or would I need to edit the texture image? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can either create 2 face rings around your socket and give them another material, or use only one material that has an Image Texture of 2 blue stripes over white background (this method is a bit cleaner)